# Where to put question mark in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, capitalization

Which one of the three sentences is correct regarding the place of "!" and capitalizing "because"?

> 1. Could you please explain to me the course enrolment process? Because it is a bit unclear for me.
> 2. Could you please explain to me the course enrolment process, because it is a bit unclear for me?
> 3. Could you please explain to me the course enrolment process? because it is a bit unclear for me.

Comment: A question mark always goes at the end of a sentence. 1 and 2 are OK, the third is not.

Comment: Regarding (2) - some people would frown on starting a sentence with 'Because'.

Comment: In informal writing, you can have question marks in the middle of sentences. In formal English, (1) is ruled out because the second sentence doesn't contain a main clause, (3) is ruled out because the question mark doesn't end a sentence, so you're left with (2).

Comment: @PeterShor I wouldn't say a question mark in the middle of a *sentence* is ever OK (unless we count chatspeak, but there grammar and spelling go out of the window anyway), but 1) is fine in informal speech/writing (while being two sentences).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one seems wrong not just grammatically but also from the implied meaning. Even if you were to use a sentence beginning with 'Because', using it right after a question indirectly implies that it is related to the answer. But here, you intend to convey part of your question through that clause.
The third one is wrong since the question mark does not end the sentence as @Peter_Shor has commented. In another sense, it is a less punctuated version of the first one as well.
This leaves you with the second, which seems about right.

**Tip**: The only times you'd see a question mark before the end of a sentence is when there is a quotation in the sentence or when the sentence is a question-exclamation; eg:

> "Why did he do it?" asked the teacher.
>
> Isn't it shocking to learn about the incident?!

Comment: Are you sure about the first one? Because it seems just fine to me.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Grammatically it is wrong. If you say that, you can make it feel right but, in the process, you shift to the second sentence

Comment: I'd argue otherwise. Starting a sentence with a conjunction is [not an error](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/starting-a-sentence-with-a-conjunction/), and it's especially common in my experience for *because* - you ask a question ("Are you sure?"), and then you clarify it in a separate sentence ("Because I think...")

Comment: @MaciejStachowski starting with a conjunction may not be wrong but here it is. That is because the conjunction is not used to answer the question but to supplement the question

Comment: I disagree. Introducing a sentence split in this way for emphasis is extremely common, and I don't think it's right to call it "grammatically wrong". "Informal", perhaps, but even in formal text I wouldn't bat an eye if someone wrote "Are you sure?/Could you clarify? Because..."

Comment: I understand your argument but not all 'informal' statements are grammatically right. And I highly doubt that this is close to formal. A formal version should mostly replace 'because' with 'as' or 'since'.
If you try speaking aloud the first sentence, you'd realize that, in order to convey the true sense of the clause that begins with the conjunction, it has to be a part of the question. There is nothing grammatically wrong in having a separate sentence starting with 'because' but it is contextually incorrect in the current setting.